# В блоке с position: relative; не работает форма. Что не так и как исправить?

Tags: html, css, form, position

```css
.block-search {
  z-index: -1;
  height: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../img/block-search.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.block-search:before {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
}
.block-search:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../img/block-search1.png);
}
.block-search h1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 55px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "GothamProMedium";
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-search">
  <h1>What are you looking for?</h1>
  <form action="#" method="get" class="form-search">
    <select name="city" id="city">
      <option value="dubay">Dubay</option>
      <option value="curitiba">Curitiba</option>
      <option value="vancouver">Vancouver</option>
      <option value="reykjavik">Reykjavik</option>
      <option value="oregon">Oregon</option>
      <option value="london">London</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="otpr">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `.block-search` пропишите `z-index` больше `-1`.

Comment: @димаовчаров, значит меняйте разметку. Сейчас `::before` и `::after` перекрывают вашу форму.

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо.